# How do I filter Totals in Cognos for a particular number?

Tags: cognos

I have created a calculation in Cognos 11 to Total a number of rows

I want to search the total for all cumulative numbers over a particular amount, let's say 4.

I have created a detailed filter [Total(Amount:Num)}>'4' and a summary filter >4 but neither are working. I'm assuming this is very simple to to, but I have come up with a blank!

Any suggestions/help, will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused.  You want to filter based on the total at the bottom of your report?

Answer (score 1):

Change your filter property to AFTER aggregation